# Render data from my model RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a website using Ruby on Rails. I met a problem which i need to display my data as text on my web page for example `<h2><%=@permits.permitstart%></h2>`but i keep getting this error

```
NoMethodError in Permits#show
Showing C:/Users/GaryVLC/RubymineProjects/Parking_and_Safety_3/app/views/permits/show.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `permitstart' for #<Permit::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb69e290>
```

I'm not sure whether I'm inputing the correct stuff in my controller. Can you guys please have a look? Any help is appreciated!

This is the web page I want my data be render (show.html.erb)

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Permit') %>
<h1>Permit Application</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <h2><%=@permits.permitstart%></h2></br>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is the web page that the button clink into the (show.html.erb)

```
<h2>My Permits</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Permit Start Date</th>
    <th>Permit End Data</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th> </th>
  </tr>
  <% @permits.each do |permit| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= permit.permitstart %></td>
        <td><%= permit.permitend %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Detail', viewpermit_path(permit) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_permit_path(permit) %></td>
      </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>
```

This is my permits controller

```
class PermitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:destroy]
  def index
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @permits = Permit.new
  end

  def create
    @permits = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    if @permits.save
      redirect_to invoice_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    Permit.destroy_all(user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Permit was successfully canceled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def confirm
    @fields = %i[vehicle_type, carplate, studentid, name, department, permitstart, permitend]
    @permit = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    render :new and return unless @permit.valid?
  end

  def show
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    @permits = Permit.where(user_id: current_user).take
    respond_to do |format|
      if @permits.update(permit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path}
        flash[:success] = "Permit successfully updated"
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
    #@permits = Permit.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: params[:id])
  end
  def detail

  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def permit_params
    params.require(:permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :studentid, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend)
  end
end
```

This is my route.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :permits do
    collection do
      post :confirm
    end
  end
  resources :visitor_permits
  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'viewpermit' =>'permits#show'

  get 'invoice' => 'permits#invoice'
  get 'payment' =>'transaction#new'
  get 'show_visitor_permit' =>'visitor_permits#show'
  get 'show_permit' =>'permits#index'
  get 'visitorpermit' => 'visitor_permits#new'
  post 'createpermit' => 'permits#create'
  get 'homepage/index'
  post 'permits' => 'permits#create'
  get 'permitapplication' => 'permits#new'
  get 'adminlogin' => 'admin_controller#index'
  get 'patrollogin' => 'patrol_officer_controller#index'
  get 'createcitation' => 'citations#new'
  get 'contact'=> 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  post 'users' => 

'users#create'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' #Page for a new session
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' #Create a new session
  delete 'logout'=>'sessions#destroy' #Delete a session


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Looks like your show action is setup wrong (it typically should find a single record/object but your returning a collection).  Check out the docs and @richardpeck answer below.   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles

Comment: can u post the params passed when you click 'detail'  link in console please?

Comment: Sorry what did you mean the params passed?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling an instance method on a *collection* object (the method doesn't exist).

You'll need to loop through the `@permits` object and call `permitstart` on each *model* object it contains:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Permit') %>
<h1>Permit Application</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <% @permits.each do |p| %>
      <h2><%= p.permitstart %></h2></br>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

--

Alternatively, if you're seeing this error in the `show` action, you need to use the following:

```
def show
  @permits = current_user.permits.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but i got this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PermitsController#show
Couldn't find Permit without an ID which pointing toward my SHOW action

Comment: That means your routes are setup incorrectly - can you paste your routes and how you're accessing your `show` action?

Answer (score 0):

Because this method

```
def show
  @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Gives you a relation (an ActiveRecord_Relation), not a single Permit object. You could take the first one but I don't know if it's what you want. Anyway, this is the issue.

```
@permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's an ActiveRecord_Relation, that means I can't take the attribute value from the model?

Comment: It means it's not a permit but they are N permits. You need ONE permit to call a method of the permit object.

Comment: Oh I see, so should i replace it with this @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])? What i want is just a permit

Comment: Yes, that's a way(not the only one) to have a single object :)

Comment: I tried that before, but i got this error after i replace ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PermitsController#show
Couldn't find Permit with 'id'=. Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: That means you're not finding the object with that id and it's another problem. Could we see your routes file?

Comment: Yep i had attached my route.db with my question.